# Remove duplicates from a 2D array in perl

Tags: perl

I have a 2D array in perl whose data is coming as rows in html format from a DB like the data shown below:

```
<tr><td>Rafa</td><td>Nadal</td><td>Data1</td></tr>,
<tr><td>Goran</td><td>Ivan</td><td>Data2</td></tr>,
<tr><td>Leander</td><td>Paes</td><td>Data2</td></tr>,
<tr><td>Leander</td><td>Paes</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
```

i want to remove the duplicate rows from the array. 
`"<tr><td>Leander</td><td>Paes</td><td>Data2</td></tr>"` should be removed in above case.
I tried the below piece of code, but it's not working out.

```
sub unique {
     my %seen;
     grep ! $seen{ join $;, @$_ }++, @_
}
```

Comment: You've quoted what looks like the source to your 2D array, but you haven't actually quoted the contents of the 2D array..  Try putting `use Data::Dumper; print Data::Dumper->Dump([\@_], ['*_']);`right after the `my %seen` line, and give us the output that provides.  I ask this, because there are multiple ways one could convert that table into a 2D array, and that could change the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: you really should try not to use outdated Perl syntax and side effects.

Second: the answer depends on the data structure you generate from the input. Here are two example implementations:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# 2D Array: list of array references
my @data = (
    ['Rafa', 'Nadal', 'Data1'],
    ['Goran', 'Ivan', 'Data2'],
    ['Leander', 'Paes', 'Data2'],
    ['Leander', 'Paes', 'Data2'],
);
my %seen;

foreach my $unique (
    grep {
        not $seen{
            join('', @{ $_ })
        }++
    } @data
) {
    print join(',', @{ $unique }), "\n";
}
print "\n";

# List of "objects", keys are table column names
@data = (
    { first => 'Rafa',    last => 'Nadal', data => 'Data1' },
    { first => 'Goran',   last => 'Ivan',  data => 'Data2' },
    { first => 'Leander', last => 'Paes',  data => 'Data2' },
    { first => 'Leander', last => 'Paes',  data => 'Data2' },
);
%seen = ();

my @key_order = qw(first last data);

foreach my $unique (
    grep {
        not $seen{ 
            join('', @{ $_ }{ @key_order } )
        }++
    } @data
) {
    print join(',', @{ $unique }{ @key_order }), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
Rafa,Nadal,Data1
Goran,Ivan,Data2
Leander,Paes,Data2

Rafa,Nadal,Data1
Goran,Ivan,Data2
Leander,Paes,Data2
```

Answer (score 3):

The shown sub is good for the job, with an array which for elements has array references. That is indeed a basic way to organize 2D data, where your rows are arrayrefs.

There are modules that can be leveraged for this, but this good old method works fine as well

```
use warnings;
use strict;    
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

sub uniq_arys {
    my %seen; 
    grep { not $seen{join $;, @$_}++ } @_; 
} 

my @data = ( 
    [ qw(one two three) ],  
    [ qw(ten eleven twelve) ],  
    [ qw(10 11 12) ],  
    [ qw(ten eleven twelve) ],  
); 

my @data_uniq = uniq_arys(@data); 

dd \@data_uniq;
```

Prints as expected (last row is gone), using [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to show data.

The sub works by joining each array into a string, and those are then checked for duplicates using a hash. The [$;](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$;) is a *subscript separator*, and an empty string `''` is just fine instead.

This approach creates a lot of ancillary data -- in principle doubles the data -- and if performance becomes a problem it may be better to simply compare element-wise (at the cost of complexity). This can be an issue only with rather large data sets.

---

A module example: use `uniq_by` from [List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy#uniq_by)

```
use List::UtilsBy qw(uniq_by);

my @no_dupes = uniq_by { join '', @$_ } @data;
```

This does, more or less, the same as the sub above.